# Can't install HP printer on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, printing, hp

I have a network HP printer at work. The model of the printer is HP Color LaserJet Pro M478f. Recently, the printer dissappeared from the list of printers after some random update on Ubuntu 20.04. I decided that's it's time to upgrade to 22.04, the upgrade went very smooth, but again the printer can not be installed.
The Printers section in Ubuntu settings is completely empty. The only thing I can do is to click "Add printer" button. Once I do that, I can find my printer by typing it's IP address, and then Ubuntu opens a window "Select printer driver" and the system never stops loading drivers database, until it complains that "Printers are not responding."
I also tried to use hp-setup. It can detect the printer when I enter the IP address manually, but then the windows is frozen and it keeps give me a message "hp-toolbox is not responding".

Any ideas please??

Comment: HP make a lot of printers :). Knowing your exact model would be helpful.

Comment: have you tried adding the printer from scratch on 22.04 in `Printers` [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: The model of the printer is HP Color LaserJet Pro M478f, if this can help somehow.

Comment: The HP Color LaserJet Pro M478f is an IPP printer that does driverless printing. Give `lpstat -l -e`.

Comment: lpstat -l -e gave no output. May be it does driverless printing when connected via USB, but not in from the network?

Comment: On 22.04 driverless printing works for both with a modern printer.

Comment: Perhaps, it supposed to work, but it does not. Ubuntu is not able to find a single network printer. This is the reality.